# mysql paste a long list of values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large database with many tables with several thousand records.

I have done some Excel work to identify some records / rows I want to delete from one of my large tables, as when I tried to do the query within phpmyadmin, the table kept locking as the query was too big.

Anyway.... Long story short.

I now have a list of 1500 records I need to delete from one of my tables.

Is there a way to "paste" these 1500 values into a query, so I can bring back the matching records, select them all at once and delete them?

Obviously, I dont want to do this manually one at a time.

So the query I have in mind is something like this:

- Find any records which match these IDs (WHERE ID = )
- Paste in list of IDs from Ms Excel
- Results returned
- Can select all rows and delete

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: paste the values comma separated, i.e. `WHERE ID IN (5,6,7,8,9,11,23,44,55,56,57,58)`. Rough enough and same useful.

Comment: query was too big? then increase `max_allowed_packet` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: You could also construct a 'temporary' table, insert the values into that and then join that onto your main table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Keyword "IN" in your query with your list of value. Like :

```
Select Name
From Users
Where ID IN (1,2,3,4 .....) ;
```

Comment: When I try to run that query (WHERE `post_title` IN ) it says #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `post_title` IN

Comment: Give the complete syntax without the list of ids

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this.

**First:**
You can directly paste the list of coma separated IDs in the where clause.

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4);
```

It you get error 'Packet Too Large' you can increase [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html)

> The largest possible packet that can be transmitted to or from a MySQL
>   5.0 server or client is 1GB.

**Second:**
You can export you Excel file to csv file and load the data to a temp table then delete fro the table using the tmp table as reference

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'X:\filename.csv'
    INTO TABLE tmptable
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

DELETE t1 
    FROM tablename t1
    JOIN tmptable t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Reference: [MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Don't forget to remove your tmp table.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `post_title` IN

Comment: can you post the sql you were trying to use?

Comment: Sorted there was an error with some missing ' on each term :)